# Get aggregated view of many to many relationships

Tags: sql, sqlite, postgresql

I have a table with 3 columns in many to many relationships with other tables.

Example:

Main

```
| id | brief_id | location_id | company_id | author_id |
|----|----------|-------------|------------|-----------|
| 1  | 22       | 4323        | 9876       | 9762      |
| 2  | 33       | 2675        | 6543       | 1643      |
| 3  | 44       | 2345        | 3445       |           |
```

Intermediate Tables:

```
Location_int
| id | brief_id | location_id |
|----|----------|-------------|
| 1  | 22       | 5413        |
| 2  | 22       | 9833        |
| 3  | 22       | 2364        |

Company_int
| id | brief_id | company_id |
|----|----------|------------|
| 1  | 22       | 6231       |
| 2  | 22       | 6134       |
| 3  | 22       | 2364       |

Author_int
| id | brief_id | author_id |
|----|----------|-----------|
| 1  | 22       | 1345      |
| 2  | 22       | 9213      |
| 3  | 22       | 7255      |
```

Joining tables

```
Location
| id   | location |
|------|----------|
| 5413 | Japan    |
| 9833 | India    |
| 2364 | Africa   |

Company
| id   | Company   |
|------|-----------|
| 5413 | Google    |
| 9833 | Microsoft |
| 2364 | Paypal    |

Author
| id   | Author |
|------|--------|
| 5413 | Tina   |
| 9833 | Saleen |
| 2364 | Sonny  |
```

What I want is to join all these tables and get:

```
| brief_id | location             | company                   | Author             |
|----------|----------------------|---------------------------|--------------------|
| 22       | Japan, India, Africa | Google, Microsoft, Africa | Tina, Saleen, Sony |
```

Locations, company and authors - sometimes all of them - can be null, in which case I want to see null values.

I tried doing a left join like this:

```
SELECT
  aur.brief_id,
  string_agg(l.name, ';'),
  string_agg(c.name, ';'),
  string_agg(a.name, ';')

FROM analytics_url_redirect aur
  LEFT JOIN location_int li
    ON bbl.brief_id = aur.brief_id
  LEFT JOIN location l
    ON l.id = li.location_id

  LEFT JOIN company_int ci
    ON bba.brief_id = aur.brief_id
  LEFT JOIN company c
    ON c.id = ci.agency_id

  LEFT JOIN author_int ai
    ON bba2.brief_id = aur.brief_id
  LEFT JOIN author a
    ON a.id = ai.author_id

GROUP BY aur.brief_id;
```

But that gives me Locations, company and Author repeated multiple times.
Something like:

```
| brief_id | location                                                         | company                                              | Author             |
|----------|------------------------------------------------------------------|------------------------------------------------------|--------------------|
| 22       | Japan, India, Africa, Japan, India, Africa, Japan, India, Africa | Google, Microsoft, Africa, Google, Microsoft, Africa | Tina, Saleen, Sony |
```

What would be a better query to accomplish this? (In PostgreSQL preferably)
Also points for a query which would be well optimized.
FYI all the columns are indexed.

Comment: **Please** provide a http://sqlfiddle.com/ for this sort of thing, so we don't have to make the tables by hand. +1 for providing sample data and expected results at all. (Created one from your data using SQLFiddle's "text to DDL" but it's a pain: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/92dfc)

Comment: What purpose do those `int` tables serve? They seem to convey no useful additional information at all.

Comment: ... and the data in the `main` table doesn't correspond to that in the `location` or `location_int` tables at all. Bogus data?

Answer (score 0):

Tables such as `location` and `company` do not have a join condition or WHERE filter between *them*, so joining them results in all possible combinations of rows.

You have to compute the other objects for each brief in separate subqueries:

```
SELECT brief_id,
       (SELECT group_concat(location)
        FROM Location_int AS li
        JOIN Location AS l ON li.location_id = l.id
        WHERE li.brief_id = aur.brief_id
       ) AS locations,
       (SELECT group_concat(Company)
        FROM Company_int AS ci
        JOIN Company AS c ON ci.company_id = c.id
        WHERE ci.brief_id = aur.brief_id
       ) AS companies,
       (SELECT group_concat(Author)
        FROM Author_int AS ai
        JOIN Author AS a ON ai.author_id = a.id
        WHERE ai.brief_id = aur.brief_id
       ) AS authors
FROM analytics_url_redirect AS aur
```

(Replace `group_concat` with `string_agg` for PostgreSQL.)